# ¿Como entregar privilegios para acceso multiusuario?

Tags: php

```
  <li class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="javascript:;" >
                            <i class=" icon-layers"></i>
                            <span>Productos</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li class="sub-menu">
                                <a  href="#">Categoría</a>
                                <ul class="sub">
                                    <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/categoria">Registrar Categoría</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="sub-menu">
                                <a  href="#">Marca</a>
                                <ul class="sub">
                                    <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/marca">Registrar Marca</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="sub-menu">
                                <a  href="#">Producto</a>
                                <ul class="sub">
                                    <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/producto">Registrar Producto</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <i class=" icon-people"></i>
                            <span>Proveedores</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/proveedor">Registrar Proveedor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <i class="icon-user-follow"></i>
                            <span>Empleados</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/empleado">Registrar Empleado</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <i class="icon-user"></i>
                            <span>Usuario</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/perfil">Registrar Perfil</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <i class=" ti-shift-right"></i>
                            <span>Entradas</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/entrada">Registrar Entrada</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            <i class="ti-shift-left"></i>
                            <span>Salidas</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a  href="<?php echo $raiz; ?>mercedes/salida">Registrar Salida</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Mi sistema cuenta con los módulos de registrar productos , registrar proveedor , registrar empleado, registrar entrada y salidas , reportes , la cuestión es que desearía saber como poder dar los privilegios para que un usuario que no es administrador, solo tenga acceso a los módulos de productos,entradas y salidas. En mi base de datos tengo tablas que son módulos perfil (para el acceso) ya que tengo otra tabla t_perfil que me indica si es administrador o empleado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bueno, podrías coger que en el momento de hacer login en una variable `$_SESSION` guardes la información del usuario que ingresó, y al momento de mostrar o no ciertas opciones lo validas con una condición, `if($_SESSION["usuario"]["permisos"] == "administrador"]{ muestra }else{ omite la información }`

Comment: Pues con bloque `if` `else` claro, cuando se cumpla una condición se comporta de la forma A y cuando no se cumple entonces la forma B

Answer (score 1):

Debes obtener el perfil del usuario y utilizarlo como variable para escribir el html en base al perfil del usuario, entonces abres PHP y verificas por ej:

```
<?php
$perfil = perfildb...
if($perfil == 1 || $perfil == "admin"){
    echo "<li class=\"sub-menu\"><a  href=\"#\">Marca</a><ul class=\"sub\"><li>";
    echo "<a  href=\"$raizmercedes/marca\">Registrar Marca</a></li></ul></li>";
}
?>
```